# How to open another fragment from inside a ViewPager fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I followed this tutorial to build an app with three fragments in sliding view (ViewPager).

https://c1ctech.com/android-viewpager-example-to-create-sliding-screens/

The app was built successfully. Then I added a button inside FragmentOne. And also created another fragment named FragmentFour with fragment_four.xml layout file.

Now I want to link the FragmentFour with FragmentOne through onClickListener with the button I created before. When in FragmentOne the button will be clicked, and it'll launch FragmentFour. To achive that, inside onClickListener I added these codes-

```
FragmentFour fragFour = new FragmentFour();
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.main_frameLayout, fragFour);
                    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    transaction.commit();
```

But after running the app, when I click on that button from inside the FragmentOne, FragmentFour's layout overlaps over the FragmentOne's layout. And FragmentTwo and FragmentThree can be accessible via sliding from FragmentFour, but I don't want this.

If anything wrong here, please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is now gone. I just need to make few changes to my codes. Inside onClickListener, I changed my codes like this-

Before:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
```

After:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
```

And inside the fragment_four.xml file's relative layout:

```
android:background="@color/bgcolor"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is replacing `FragmentOne` with `FragmentFour` in the `ViewPager`:

```
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_one, fragFour);
```

which results in a ViewPager with `FragmentFour`, `FragmentTwo`, and `FragmentThree`

It seems like you want to start a new `Activity` for `FragmentFour`.  From your `onClick` handler in `FragmentOne`, start a new activity as follows:

```
getActivity().startActivity(new Intent(context, FragmentFourActivity.class));
```

`FragmentFourActivity` is an Android Activity (e.g. `AppCompatActivity`) whose layout contains FragmentFour.  Follow along at https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity if unsure how to do so.

Comment: I don't want to start another new activity. FragmentFour.class is a fragment that extends Fragment. I just want to launch this fragment on button click from FragmentOne.

Comment: I can launch that fragment upon button click, but the newly fragment ovaerlaps on the primary one.

Comment: Your question and comments make it unclear to me what you're trying to accomplish .. .i.e. after clicking the button you expect to see FragmentFour where?  Your current code has it replacing FragmentOne within the ViewPager.